# Can I make a stool from thinner OSB

Tags: strength, board-materials

I have some leftover piece of 12mm OSB.
I want to make [this stool](http://www.abeautifulmess.com/2013/02/josh-modern-stool.html?pintix=1) out of it:
[image]
Originally it was made from 18mm plywood, obviously I need to adjust to use thinner board. 
I want to keep the weight to the minimum, and keep the strength (I'm going to stand on it occasionally to reach high shelves).

My questions are:
1) Where should it be reinforced? I'm thinking two 15*15*1 mm steel square tube along front leg: 
[image]
and 20*20*2 mm steel angle bar along the center of the back leg.

2) How should I join the corners? Original screws to the edge seems unreliable for a thin board. I'm thinking screws to aluminum angle bar.

Comment: Thinner board is weaker sand more flexible. Two layers glued together would give you thicker/stiffer/stronger material...

Comment: I would think that it would likely be less expensive and of much simpler construction (as well as prettier, though that's quite subjective) to build the stool out of some 18mm OSB than to buy and attach the bar stock to the wood. I do understand the desire to use up some existing scrap, but I'm not sure this is the project for it.

Comment: @FreeMan, 15 or 18mm  OSB is another option I'm considering.  
My other concern is whether glued screws in the edge of OSB would hold through the abuse of moving the stool around.

Comment: Good point about the screws into the edge of the OSB. Using [Stoppal's](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/4132/93) suggestion of reinforcing all the areas that accept screws along the edges sounds like a great idea, and would probably allow you to use your thinner material up.

Comment: Apologies if this is too blunt or rude, but I think OSB is a terrible choice for this design. Maybe maybe it would work if you didn't cut a great gaping hole, but even then... OSB? If someone put a gun to my head, I'd at least clad the edges in an aluminum or steel U-channel so you weren't perpetually catching clothing and skin on those nasty edges.

Comment: @FreeMan I've made [calculations for the weakest element](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/9097/5053) and it seems that I can get away with even thinner OSB, even 6 mm thick leg wouldn't buckle.

Comment: *"it seems that I can get away with even thinner OSB, even 6 mm thick leg wouldn't buckle"* but could you join it successfully? 12mm is fine in terms of strength but I wouldn't go any thinner than this. People regularly underestimate 12mm material for strength, recommending 18mm when it's complete overkill e.g. for shop storage, where they worry about whether it can take the weight of a few planes and some other hand tools!

Answer (score 1):

My first approach would be to glue some 2 cm (~ 3/4 in) strips of the same material to all the places that get screwed and to the edges of the side parts. That gives you 24 mm (~ 1 in) of material to hold your screws which should be plenty.

If the stool isn't too tall the 12 mm wall material should be rigid enough to withstand the pressure of a medium sized man. With doubled thickness in the screwed places you should achieve a sturdy enough stool.

---

On a different note, I made similar stools out of spruce (18 mm, 3 layered plywood) last year and decided to put the bottom part that joins the two sides on the outside of one side. That gave the stool some extra rigidity and they are stackable now.

Comment: It's a bar stool, 60-70 cm overall height.

Comment: I gathered as much, i still think it's doable though :) I'd nevertheless be cautious when standing on it for the first time ;)

Comment: @Stoppal I like your design.  Besides making the stools stackable, the relocation of the bottom part gives a person another place to rest her feet.